# how to add_image_size working with smaller image?

Tags: wordpress

I added add_image_size in functions.php and its resize the images when the image is large enough, but when the image is smaller than the size its not resize the image.

For example, i added `add_image_size( 'category', 255, 150, true );`. 
But user upload some image with size `150x150`, it's not large enough.

This my code for resize image when it's smaller than the size i need:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'mit_resize') ) {
    function mit_resize( $attachment, $width, $height, $url = false, $crop = true ) {

    $siteurl = get_option( 'siteurl' );

    if ( $url === false ) {
        $file_path = get_attached_file( $attachment );
    } else if ( $attachment ) {
        $file_path = get_attached_file(mit_get_attachment_id($attachment));
    }
    if ( empty($file_path) )
        return false;

    $file_info = pathinfo( $file_path );
    $extension = '.'. $file_info['extension'];
    $base_file = $file_info['dirname'].'/'.$file_info['filename'].$extension;

    $sizes = mit_get_image_sizes();
    $general = getimagesize($base_file);
    foreach ($sizes as $key => $size) {
        if($size['width'] == $width && $size['height'] == $height && $general[0] >= $size['width'] && $general[1] >= $size['height']) {
            $path = explode('wp-content',$file_info['dirname'].'/'.$file_info['filename'].'-'.$width.'x'.$height.$extension);
            return $siteurl . '/wp-content' . $path[1];
        }

    }

    if (file_exists($base_file))
    {
        $no_ext_path = $file_info['dirname'].'/'.$file_info['filename'];

        $img_resize = wp_get_image_editor( $no_ext_path.$extension);
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $img_resize ) ) {
            $cropped_img_path = $no_ext_path.'-'.$width.'x'.$height.$extension;
            $img_resize->resize( $width, $height, $crop );
            $img_resize->save($cropped_img_path);
            if (preg_match("/wp-content/", $cropped_img_path) != false) {
                $path = explode('wp-content',$cropped_img_path);
            }
            else
                return 'http://placehold.it/' . $width .'x' . $height . '?text=Img';
            $url_file = $siteurl . '/wp-content' .$path[1];
        }
    }

    if ( !file_exists($cropped_img_path) )
    {
        return 'http://placehold.it/' . $width .'x' . $height . '?text=Img';
    }
    else
        return $url_file;
}
```

}

Can i hook this function to add_image_size?

Comment: it is not possible. you can set valition for upload min. size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer for anybody who needs that:

```
if(!function_exists('mit_thumbnail_upscale')) {
function mit_thumbnail_upscale( $default, $orig_w, $orig_h, $new_w, $new_h, $crop ){

    if ( !$crop ) return null; // let the wordpress default function handle this

    $aspect_ratio = $orig_w / $orig_h;
    $size_ratio = max($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);

    $crop_w = round($new_w / $size_ratio);
    $crop_h = round($new_h / $size_ratio);

    $s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
    $s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );

    return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
}
}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'mit_thumbnail_upscale', 10, 6 );
```

After `add_image_size`, you just put this code into the function. If the client uploads an image smaller than your size, don't worry, `mit_thumbnail_upscale` will help you.

Comment: This is a great snippet, thanks :)